# QGIS Grid naming different

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

Is it possible to name a GRID with letters and also not from top down but from left to right?

[image: on the screenshot you see that it starts left top and goes down to right top. is it possible to start left top with A1, A2,... for the first row and B1, B2, B3, for the second row?]

Comment: Could you provide screenshots/images of your desired outcome, and tell us, what you tried so far?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296758/sorting-grid-cells-in-fishnet-grid-by-location-and-number-using-qgis/296762#296762