# QGIS - row numbers by location

Tags: qgis, geolocation, calculate

Is there a possibility to add continuous numbers in a seperated row that based on their location? Like f.e. from north to south, or left to right. i used row_number, but the numbers seem to be coincidental...[image: example pic]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296758/sorting-grid-cells-in-fishnet-grid-by-location-and-number-using-qgis/296762#296762

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this `Field Calculator expression` for numbering north to south for instance:

```
array_find(
           array_agg(y($geometry), -- list the Y coordinates
           order_by:=-1*y($geometry)), -- order by descending Y coordinates

           y($geometry)) -- finds the current feature Y coordinate index in the array
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can create a Virtual Layer and use [row_number function](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/), ordered by for example each features centroid y coordinate:

```sql
select *, row_number() over(order by st_y(centroid(geometry))) as newid
from ak_riks
```

ID increasing from south to north:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

To order the features (e.g.) west to east, you can use this expression on a new field in the layer:

```
array_find(                         -- find the position of the current feature in the array (this becomes the calculated value)
    aggregate(                      -- create an array of all the feature ids in the layer
        layer:='your_layer_name',   -- the name of your layer 
        aggregate:='array_agg', 
        expression:=$id, 
        order_by:=x($geometry)      -- order the points west to east
    ),
    $id                             -- the current feature id
) + 1                               -- start the 'position id' at 1 instead of 0
```

It will number the features 1, ..., N<sub>features</sub> with their position.

[image]

Comment: Yes indeed, you can add 1 to the value returned by `array_find`, see my edit.

Comment: I am not sure if I did something wrong but my results are identical to $id...

array_find (
 aggregate
 (layer:='layername in my project',
 aggregate:='array_agg',
 expression:=$id,
  order_by:=x($geometry)
  ),
$id) + 1